# Rails validate float limited to 2 decimal places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

In my model Car i have a attribute price in float, now i must validates this price to only accept price that is limited to 2 decimal places.
I try with

> `validates :price, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01,
>   less_than_or_equal_to: 99.99 }`

But still i have red spec. How to round this with validation?

EDIT:

spec:

> ```
> describe '#price' do
>   let(:car) { build(:car, price: 2.345) }
>   it 'is limited to two decimal places' do
>     expect(car).to_not be_valid
>   end
> end
> ```

error msg:

```
> Failure/Error: expect(car).to_not be_valid expected #<Car id: nil,
 name: "MyName", description: "MyDESC", price: 2.345, created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil, category_id: nil, user_id: nil> not to be valid
```

Comment: show your spec code..

Comment: I tend to do prices in pennies (integers) to avoid any float errors.  Then create some helpers to read/write the price in dollars.

Comment: why it is not valid ? It should be valid...2.345 is in your range.

Comment: i must limit this price to only two places after .

Comment: I found :format => { :with => /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, and with this spec is green.
Its any other way to solve this without regex ?

Comment: Do not use floating point for this. Use integer pennies or a `decimal` column with appropriate precision and scale (assuming of course that you're not using the crappy Rails default SQLite database of course).

Comment: I agree with @mu is too short. Do not store price as decimal, rather store it as integer.